# Named anchor tags landing on the middle of the div and not the top

Tags: php, html, anchor

I am using named anchor tags to hyperlink to a div on another page. These hyperlinks land on the middle of the div causing the critical heading to not be seen. 
Example, This [link](https://pacific-tundra-2884.herokuapp.com/Services.php#Cloud) lands on the middle of the div and this is how it looks:

[image]

I want it to land on the heading 'Awesome Service Description' and on landing should look like this:

[image]

Relevant Code is this:

```
<div class="container" id="Cloud">

      <div class="three-fourth last-in-row">
        <!-- Intro -->
        <h1 class="intro-header">Awesome <strong>service</strong> description</h1>
        <p class="intro" style="padding:3%; margin-left: -2.5%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit vehicula est, in consequat libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <!-- End of intro -->
        <p style="margin:0;">Donec a lectus lectus. Nullam sed lorem lacus. Aliquam et porttitor velit. Aenean bibendum, mauris id rhoncus egestas, tellus leo imperdiet turpis, ac tincidunt lacus sem vitae nisl. Sed sit amet urna ut neque dapibus imperdiet at at orci. Proin diam lectus, fringilla eu volutpat id, tristique ut nisi. Suspendisse sed nulla sed erat scelerisque consequat at ac quam. Maecenas mattis at turpis sit amet sagittis. </p>
        <h3 style="padding:2%;"><strong>Why</strong> Us?</h3>
        <ul class="check">
            <li>Quisque mollis, nunc porta sodales tincidunt, ante nunc convallis lacus, et sodales erat libero vitae risus. Sed vehicula, sapien eu egestas dapibus, ipsum elit laoreet tortor, a dapibus justo tortor quis metus. </li>
            <li>Etiam ultricies, lorem at ultrices rutrum, massa ante tempus diam, venenatis varius arcu magna mattis mi.</li>
            <li>Quisque mollis, nunc porta sodales tincidunt, ante nunc convallis lacus, et sodales erat libero vitae risus. Sed vehicula, sapien eu egestas dapibus, ipsum elit laoreet tortor, a dapibus justo tortor quis metus. </li>
            <li>Etiam ultricies, lorem at ultrices rutrum, massa ante tempus diam, venenatis varius arcu magna mattis mi.</li>
        </ul>
```

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

- Code is working fine.
- Problem is, you have used fixed header.
- Your fix header overlap some part of div which you are trying show.

Solution is.

- give that id to "Service features" just above "Awesome service
  description".
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might get a scroll animation to add on some extra pixels to push down your page to reveal the anchor from under your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var getId   =   $(window.location.hash);
var Offset  =   getId.offset();
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (Offset.top-120) }, 'slow');
</script>
```